# iOS - Localizing StoryBoard file

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard, nslocalizedstring

I've heard arguments on localizing a StoryBoard file (the way apple recommends - might) not be a good idea. The recommended way is to highlight storyboard in the project navigation and then localize it by clicking a language in the file inspector.

Here is the other way suggested: Remove all strings from the storyboard and in the ViewController file itself load the localized Strings per UI element.  The argument for this is that multiple storyboard files are created per localization and the UI constraints are sometimes not kept.  You end up with localized storyboards that have different UI constraints.  Thus the storyboards are not identical in layout.  Can anyone verify if this is the case?

I have  a task to localize a few storyboards and want to know all your ideas and best approach ? BTW not all my layouts that i have inherited from other developers are auto-layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in the previous version of xcode below xcode 6 it duplicates storyboards when localizing them.  In the newer version of xcode it does not duplicate the storyboard. Instead it creates a text localization file and keeps just one storyboard.  You can localize the storyboard the same way as you localize any file from the file inspector.